python code running as a service to record and play audio
i have a python code running as a service on Raspberry Pi 4. The app is basically to record some audio in a certain language using a microphone, save the audio to a .wav file, then use speech_recognition to recognize the language, then i use translators library and gTTS to transcribe, translate and convert the audio recorded to a desired language in .mp3, then i use playsound from betterplaysound library to play the .mp3 file.
Everything works perfectly fine on VS Code virtual environment. However when i run the python code as a background service it does not work. the recording works fine and save it to a .wav file, but playing the audio does not work.
code to save audio to .wav file (works fine)
with wave.open(wav_audio_file, 'w') as f:

    f.setparams((1, 2, 16000, 0, "NONE", "NONE"))
    f.writeframes(struct.pack("h" * len(audio), *audio))

code to convert .wav file to .mp3 file
with sr.AudioFile(wav_audio_file) as source:
     audio = recognizer.record(source)
     try:
        text_to_translate = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language='en-GB')

what i could be missing! thanks in advance.
here is the error traceback as shown by the service log:
File "/home/pi/projects/my-project/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 274, in __enter__
Oct 31 11:55:33 raspberrypi4 python3[1463]:     raise ValueError("Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format")
Oct 31 11:55:33 raspberrypi4 python3[1463]: ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format


could it be a path issue? if you're using relative paths it would probably break if the script is not launched from the same location

Thank you @folengateis, i am not using relative paths. please check the updated question with stacktrace. i tried both os.path.abspath and os.path.realpath to access the successfully recorder .wav file. However, i think the problem lays somewhere else :(

the traceback talks about wrong file format, but doesn't provide the file path. is it complete? if both methods use the same code with the same environment, it should work.

i just noted that you forgot the binary flag, it should be with wave.open(wav_audio_file, 'wb')

sorry for the late reply @folengateis, the file path is fine i believe, like i said it works perfectly fine on VS Code with the same file paths. Also, i have tried with both "w" and "wb" and still the same issue.

Anyone can help please! cannot find a way around :(
